# Compiling GMP Library on Windows

Tags: makefile, codeblocks, gmp

I've downloaded and extracted the files for the GMP library. My objective is to use this library working with my c++ code with code::blocks as my IDE. I have verified that there is a makefile among the files that I extracted. In fact, there are two make files, makefile.am and makefile.in.

Assuming that these files are what I need, I open a command prompt and navigate to the folder where these makefiles are stored (c:\cpplibs\gmp).  From there, I type 'make' and hit enter with the expectation that this will compile the library and I can then link to it from code::blocks.

However, I immediately get an error message from the command prompt:

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I checked the Path variable and the path where my make.exe file is stored is in this string, so I don't think that is the problem. I haven't used Make before in a Windows environment, so I'm stuck. Am I using Make correctly here? Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

(edit: I'm posting a couple of screen shots to show how I have Make set up and that the Path variable points to it)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are autoconf/automake files rather than regular make files so they won't work without the GNU tools.

Look into getting [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) to build this, or you might try Cygwin, which can be simpler if you don't mind the cygwin dependency.

Also, the error message is indicating that make is not in your path, despite what you think.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into MinGW (I'm trying to use GNU GCC). I added a couple of screen shots to show how I have Make set up. Is there anything that you see there that sheds light on why I get that error message? Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It echoes the exact string that appears when I edit the path in system properties. That string includes the folder where make.exe exists.

Answer (score 0):

I make the compilation in windows by using instructions from this [site](https://machinecognitis.github.io/Math.Gmp.Native/html/846f5c8a-6cba-433e-9f18-cde2ff5695cd.htm):

you can find all the files to download from this site:
https://github.com/MachineCognitis/Math.Gmp.Native/tree/master/Math.Gmp.Native/Dependencies

> Building the GNU MP Library on Windows Install MSYS2.
>
> On a 64-bit computer, install msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe, and on a
> 32-bit computer, install msys2-i686-20161025.exe. You can also check
> for a more recent version of MSYS2 here. Install MSYS2 to its default
> location.
>
> After installation, you need to updates MSYS2 packages. From the
> Windows Start Menu, start MSYS2 MSYS. In the shell command window,
> enter the command:
>
> pacman -Syuu
>
> and follow instructions. You will have to close the command window,
> reopen a new one, and reenter the command pacman -Syuu.
>
> Finally, in order to build software, you need to install a number of
> packages with the command:
>
> pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-i686-toolchain
> mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain git subversion mercurial
> mingw-w64-i686-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
>
> run from the same command window as in the previous step.
>
> To build 32-bit software, use the MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit command from the
> Windows Start Menu, and for 64-bit software, use MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit.
>
> Install yasm.
>
> On a 64-bit computer, copy yasm-1.3.0-win64.exe to C:\msys64\usr\bin,
> and rename it to yasm.exe.
>
> Similarly on a 32-bit computer, copy yasm-1.3.0-win32.exe to
> C:\msys32\usr\bin, and rename it to yasm.exe.
>
> Build GNU MP.
>
> Create folders C:\Temp\x86 and C:\Temp\x64. These are the folder where
> the compiled 32-bit and 64-bit versions of GNU MP will be installed.
> Unzip gmp-6.1.2.tar.bz2 in folder C:\Temp. This puts GNU MP in
> subfolder gmp-6.1.2.
>
> In each one of the command windows openend with the commands MSYS2
> MinGW 32-bit and MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit from the Windows Start Menu, run
> the commands below:
>
> cd /c/Temp/gmp-6.1.2 ./configure --enable-fat --disable-static
> --enable-shared --prefix=/c/Temp/x86 or x64 make make check make install
>
> The --prefix specifies the install folder. Note that the Windows C:
> drive is specified as the root /C/ folder in the MinGW window. Note
> also that the configure and make commands are to be run against a
> fresly uncompressed GNU MP source. The make install command creates
> libgmp-10.dll in the C:\Temp\x86 and C:\Temp\x64 folders. These two
> compiled versions of the GNU MP library are to be copied to the x86
> and x64 folders of the Math.Gmp.Native Visual Studio projects. They
> can also be copied directly into the x86 and x64 folders of the
> bin/Debug or bin/Release folders.
>
> The 32-bit and 64-bit make check commands generate some warnings, but
> all tests passed successfully.